# the other/another girl next to you

Tags: adverbs

> 1 I recognize you in the picture. But who is **the other** girl next
> to you?
>
> 2 I recognize you in the picture. But who is **another** girl next to
> you?

I think that 2 is wrong, but I don't know why. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference between the definite and the indefinite article is that the definite article ('the') identifies a particular object or concept while the indefinite article ('a') merely categorises an object or concept as being an example of someone or something.

There aren't many contexts where "who's another girl?" would make much sense as a question. Maybe a girl could ask that question of a crowd of mostly boys if she suspects there's at least one girl among them. Maybe she's feeling a little isolated among all the males and would like a bit of female company.

Only with 'the' (or a demonstrative like "that" or "this") does the sentence actually identify who it is we want more information on.

Comment: If there are two girls in the picture, then it's clear why "the other" should be used. But what if there are many girls in the picture and there are a few standing next to the person? How come "the other" would fit?

Comment: If you want ask for information on a particular girl, you need to identify her in your question. And you always need something like "the", that" or "this" to do so.  "Who is the girl second from the left?" ; "Who is the girl in the blue sweater?"